# encrypt with keyfile, decrypt with password

Tags: php, linux, encryption, passwords

I'm fairly sure this should be simple, but somehow I've come up short from Googling.

I am writing a php script on linux to encrypt files. I want anyone to be able to encrypt files using this script, but to require a password when decrypting the files.

I looked at GnuPG and openssl but they seem to require keyfiles when decrypting too, or password both when encrypting and decrypting - unless I missed something.

Basically I am working on a repository and the project's configuration files contain sensitive information that I don't want on the repo unencrypted, but I want to have a script all developers can use to easily encrypt sensitive files before they commit them to the repo.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you cannot use a key(file) to decrypt the files? Why does it have to be a password?

Comment: That's a very good question - It comes down to how easy it is to distribute a password I guess - we use a password manager (Keepass).

However, it just gave me an idea for a hack... I could encrypt the decryption keyfile with a password, and as part of the script, decrypt the keyfile with a password, and then use the keyfile to decrypt the other files... I realise how crazy this sounds, but it might work :o

Comment: If you could use a keyfile instead of a password, you could use a public/private key pair. Then you could use the public key to encrypt the files, and the private key to decrypt the files. In this case, there is no need to give away the private key to anybody, just give the public key to the other developers.

Comment: I want it to be self-contained (have everything on the repo), so simply "git clone" would pull down everything that's needed, our password manager does not support files, so I can't add the private key to that. Now I suppose one could argue that a private key in principle just is a very long password - I COULD store it as a string and just have people paste that into a file, maybe that's the better solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand it correctly, so you want to store the key/password in the repository, sould everybody be able to decrypt the files, so what is the encryption for? A private key is not just a long password, the difference is, that it belongs tightly to a public key, you cannot choose a private key freely as you could with a password.

Comment: I'm well aware that I can't choose the private key since it's a "key pair", but let me try to explain: I will generate a keypair, have public key on repo as is so everybody can use that to encrypt config files, and then encrypt the private key with a password, and put that on the repo too, so it's possible to decrypt the private file with a password, and then decrypt config files with the private file.

Comment: Yes this solution should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After martinstoeckli asked the obvious question of "why can't you use a key to decrypt the files?", I thought I had thought of a hack, but apparently it's actually very widely used after googling around - my solution here involved using both a keypair and password.

Note: I generate the keypair in a temporary folder, else this keypair would exist on the keychain on the PC where they are generated, I do not want that, therefore I add `--homedir /tmp/gnupg`

I generate a password-less keypair with GPG - here's what I typed:
`mkdir /tmp/gnupg`
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg --full-gen-key`
`(1) RSA and RSA (default)`
`4096`
`0`
`y`
`mark`
`marklahn@domain.com`
`this key is used for protecting config files`
`o`
Then export the private key, private key and ownertrust
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg --armor --export marklahn@domain.com > gpg_keyfile.pub`
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg --armor --export-secret-keys marklahn@domain.com > gpg_keyfile.priv`
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg --export-ownertrust > gpg_ownertrust.txt`
`rm -rf /tmp/gnupg`
This is enough to encrypt and decrypt files without a password once the keys are imported to GPG's keychain.

Next up is password protecting the private key, so nobody can use it without having the password.
`gpg -c --batch --passphrase password1234 gpg_keyfile.priv`
BEWARE: GPG does NOT delete the original files, so when encrypting, remember to delete the original file if necessary
Then I can add all 3 files to the repository (`gpg_keyfile.pub gpg_keyfile.priv.gpg gpg_ownertrust.txt - NOT gpg_keyfile.priv!` ).
To encrypt a file on another machine:
1: import the public file and ownertrust
`gpg --import gpg_keyfile.pub`
`gpg --import-ownertrust gpg_ownertrust.txt`
2: encrypt the file with the public key
`gpg -e -r marklahn@domain.com configfile.ini`
configfile.ini.gpg should now exist, which can be commited to repo

Now when wanting to decrypt a file again, there's a couple of extra hoops to jump through to make sure the system doesn't save the private key.
1: First, the private key is password protected, so decrypt the private key:
`gpg --batch --passphrase password1234 gpg_keyfile.priv.gpg`
2: Then create a temporary gpg directory
`mkdir /tmp/gnupg`
3: import the private key to the temporary keychain
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg --import gpg_keyfile.priv`
4: use the temporary keychain that now holds the private key to decrypt the file
`gpg --homedir /tmp/gnupg configfile.ini.gpg`
5: make sure to immediately remove the temporary keychain and private key
`rm -rf /tmp/gnupg gpg_keyfile.priv`

That works for me, now I can git clone a branch onto a new system, easily set up my application and decrypt my config files having just a password.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using both `GnuPG` and `openssl`.

You need to have an encrypted (i.e. - password protected) private key file and an unencrypted public key file. Anyone can encrypt using the public key, but decrypting requires providing the private key, which is password protected.

The only technicality is that you will need to distribute the key files to everyone.